# How to ensure the selection direction using Alt Select

Tags: modeling, edit-mode

When you use alt select on say a sphere. The selection can go one of two ways. It can either select the latitude or longitude route around the sphere. How can I choose which way I want the selection to go, please?  Or is it totally random and you just keep clicking until it goes the way you want it to?

Cheers
Dave

Comment: Hello :). Every quad has four clickable areas - left, right, up, down. Depends on which area you click. The same applies to edges.

Comment: So simple. Thank you for your help.

Comment: No problem, glad to be of help :).

Answer (score 4):

It all depends on where you click it will try to follow the direction of the nearest component.

Comment: So simple, thank you for your help